# Create an alert based on status change (started / stopped) of a GCP VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, monitoring

I want to monitor my status changes of a GCP Compute Instance.

Is there a way to set an alert on GCP monitoring so that I get notified each time its status changes? (from started to stopped and vice versa)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For alerting on the underlying VM starting and stopping you could use the preview of [log-based alerts](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/alerting/log-based-alerts) and use the query

```
resource.type="gce_instance"
proto_payload.method_name="v1.compute.instances.start"
```

for start events, and

```
resource.type="gce_instance"
proto_payload.method_name="v1.compute.instances.stop"
```

for stop events.